# Why its possible to access class methods using signature of the interface from default method?

Tags: java, methods, interface, default

Maybe this question has obvious answer but i could not find it probably because im a java newbie.
Could you please say why in Java its possible to access class methods using signature of the interface from default method. I thought its possible to access methods only from class instance.
Example:

```
public interface test {

   String voo();

   default void foo() {
       voo().toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: `voo()` returns an instance of a `String`

Comment: Nope. That is the power of interfaces. In a sense, it is like a forward-declaration in C/C++. The call to `voo()` is resolved at runtime, i.e. the concrete implementation is called at runtime

Comment: FYI, String::toString is a redundant method call

Comment: What is wrong? In default method It can access other interface methods & other default methods.

Comment: I believe you are describing polymorphic behavior.

Comment: @Loc nothing wrong, im just trying to understand some nuances of the java that i did not see before or what was not described in tutorials.

Comment: It is what default method was designed for!!!!

Comment: @Michael, thank you, it was just an fast no sense example, but i will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JLS 9.4.3. Interface Method Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.3) it's not prohibited to call another method inside the default interface method body:

> A default method has a block body. This block of code provides an implementation of the method in the event that a class implements the interface but does not provide its own implementation of the method.

In practice default methods are not that different from class methods especially since Java 9 when one can have private interface methods:

```
public interface Test {

  String voo();

  default void foo() {
   bar();
  }

  private void bar() {
    voo().toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. You seem to just be asserting "default methods exist" and he knows that.

Answer (score 0):

**Default methods are instance methods.** ([JLS 9.4: Method declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4))

Instance methods are invoked on particular instances of objects. But a call to an instance method is made through a reference to an object of a type which declares that method. That type might be a superclass of, or an interface of, the actual object type at run time.

This allows us to write code that can operate on multiple types of objects through a common interface -- one kind of polymorphism.

Within an instance method, you can call other instance methods accessible through the type containing the calling instance method.

Optionally, you can do this through a keyword `this`, defined to be a reference to the object on which the instance method was called, of the type in which the keyword appears. The `this` keyword can be used in default methods. ([JLS 15.8.3: this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3))

So, in your case, your default method could call either `this.voo()` or just `voo()`.

```
public interface test {
   String voo();

   default void foo() {
      this.voo().toString(); // Can call an instance method accessible through this type.
      voo().toString();      // Equivalent call
   }
}
```